# Not receiving any data from Slack Slash Commands API

Tags: node.js, heroku, slack, slack-api

I have been struggling with this for the past few days, but... when I call the Slack Slash Commands with my command from the slack app, slack does not respond with any data about the command, such as a trigger_id. I want to respond to the command by calling dialog.open, but that requires a trigger_id from the command.

Currently, I am logging the response from the server; the following is printed out (I am hosting this in Heroku, so the four digit numbers are related to a timestamp I couldn't fully remove from the log easily, just ignore them. I've also ommited a large section from begining of the response due StackOverflow's character limit):

```
1699        length: 0,
1700        pipes: null,
1701        pipesCount: 0,
1703        flowing: true,
1704        ended: false,
1706        endEmitted: false,
1707        reading: true,
1709        sync: false,
1710        needReadable: true,
1711        emittedReadable: false,
1713        readableListening: false,
1714        resumeScheduled: false,
1716        paused: false,
1718        emitClose: false,
1719        destroyed: false,
1721        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
1722        awaitDrain: 0,
1724        readingMore: false,
1725        decoder: null,
1727        encoding: null },
1728     readable: true,
1730     _events:
1731      [Object: null prototype] {
1732        end: [Array],
1734        drain: [Array],
1735        timeout: [Function: socketOnTimeout],
1737        data: [Function: bound socketOnData],
1738        error: [Function: socketOnError],
1739        close: [Array],
1741        resume: [Function: onSocketResume],
1742        pause: [Function: onSocketPause] },
1744     _eventsCount: 8,
1745     _maxListeners: undefined,
1747     _writableState:
1748      WritableState {
1750        objectMode: false,
1751        highWaterMark: 16384,
1753        finalCalled: false,
1754        needDrain: false,
1755        ending: false,
1757        ended: false,
1758        finished: false,
1760        destroyed: false,
1761        decodeStrings: false,
1762        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
1764        length: 0,
1765        writing: false,
1767        corked: 0,
1768        sync: true,
1769        bufferProcessing: false,
1771        onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
1772        writecb: null,
1774        writelen: 0,
1775        bufferedRequest: null,
1777        lastBufferedRequest: null,
1778        pendingcb: 0,
1779        prefinished: false,
1781        errorEmitted: false,
1782        emitClose: false,
1783        bufferedRequestCount: 0,
1785        corkedRequestsFree: [Object] },
1786     writable: true,
1788     allowHalfOpen: true,
1789     _sockname: null,
1790     _pendingData: null,
1792     _pendingEncoding: '',
1793     server:
1800      Server {
1802        _events: [Object],
1803        _eventsCount: 2,
1804        _maxListeners: undefined,
1806        _connections: 1,
1807        _handle: [TCP],
1809        _usingWorkers: false,
1810        _workers: [],
1812        _unref: false,
1813        allowHalfOpen: true,
1814        pauseOnConnect: false,
1816        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
1817        timeout: 120000,
1818        keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
1820        _pendingResponseData: 0,
1821        maxHeadersCount: null,
1822        headersTimeout: 40000,
1824        _connectionKey: '6::::33915',
1825        [Symbol(IncomingMessage)]: [Function],
1826        [Symbol(ServerResponse)]: [Function],
1828        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 4 },
1829     _server:
1831      Server {
1832        _events: [Object],
1833        _eventsCount: 2,
1835        _maxListeners: undefined,
1836        _connections: 1,
1838        _handle: [TCP],
1839        _usingWorkers: false,
1840        _workers: [],
1842        _unref: false,
1844        allowHalfOpen: true,
1845        pauseOnConnect: false,
1847        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
1848        timeout: 120000,
1850        keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
1851        _pendingResponseData: 0,
1852        maxHeadersCount: null,
1854        headersTimeout: 40000,
1855        _connectionKey: '6::::33915',
1856        [Symbol(IncomingMessage)]: [Function],
1858        [Symbol(ServerResponse)]: [Function],
1859        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 4 },
1861     timeout: 120000,
1862     parser:
1864      HTTPParser {
1865        '0': [Function: parserOnHeaders],
1867        '1': [Function: parserOnHeadersComplete],
1868        '2': [Function: parserOnBody],
1870        '3': [Function: parserOnMessageComplete],
1871        '4': [Function: bound onParserExecute],
1873        _headers: [],
1874        _url: '',
1875        socket: [Circular],
1877        incoming: [Circular],
1878        outgoing: null,
1880        maxHeaderPairs: 2000,
1881        _consumed: true,
1883        onIncoming: [Function: bound parserOnIncoming],
1884        parsingHeadersStart: 0,
1886        [Symbol(isReused)]: true },
1887     on: [Function: socketOnWrap],
1888     _paused: false,
1890     _httpMessage:
1891      ServerResponse {
1893        _events: [Object],
1894        _eventsCount: 1,
1896        _maxListeners: undefined,
1897        output: [],
1898        outputEncodings: [],
1900        outputCallbacks: [],
1901        outputSize: 0,
1903        writable: true,
1904        _last: false,
1905        chunkedEncoding: false,
1907        shouldKeepAlive: false,
1908        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
1910        sendDate: true,
1911        _removedConnection: false,
1912        _removedContLen: false,
1914        _removedTE: false,
1915        _contentLength: null,
1916        _hasBody: true,
1918        _trailer: '',
1919        finished: false,
1921        _headerSent: false,
1922        socket: [Circular],
1924        connection: [Circular],
1925        _header: null,
1926        _onPendingData: [Function: bound updateOutgoingData],
1928        _sent100: false,
1933        _expect_continue: false,
1934        req: [Circular],
1936        locals: [Object: null prototype] {},
1937        [Symbol(isCorked)]: false,
1938        [Symbol(outHeadersKey)]: [Object] },
1940     [Symbol(asyncId)]: 178,
1941     [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
1943     [Symbol(timeout)]:
1944      Timeout {
1945        _called: false,
1947        _idleTimeout: 120000,
1948        _idlePrev: [TimersList],
1950        _idleNext: [TimersList],
1951        _idleStart: 1148319,
1952        _onTimeout: [Function: bound ],
1954        _timerArgs: undefined,
1955        _repeat: null,
1957        _destroyed: false,
1958        [Symbol(unrefed)]: true,
1960        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 179,
1961        [Symbol(triggerId)]: 178 },
1962     [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
1964     [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0 },
1965  _consuming: false,
1967  _dumped: false,
1968  next: [Function: next],
1970  baseUrl: '',
1971  originalUrl: '/create',
1973  _parsedUrl:
1974   Url {
1975     protocol: null,
1977     slashes: null,
1978     auth: null,
1979     host: null,
1981     port: null,
1982     hostname: null,
1984     hash: null,
1985     search: null,
1988     query: null,
1989     pathname: '/create',
1991     path: '/create',
1992     href: '/create',
1994     _raw: '/create' },
1995  params: {},
1996  query: {},
1998  res:
1999   ServerResponse {
2001     _events:
2002      [Object: null prototype] { finish: [Function: bound resOnFinish] },
2003     _eventsCount: 1,
2005     _maxListeners: undefined,
2011     output: [],
2012     outputEncodings: [],
2014     outputCallbacks: [],
2015     outputSize: 0,
2017     writable: true,
2018     _last: false,
2019     chunkedEncoding: false,
2021     shouldKeepAlive: false,
2022     useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
2024     sendDate: true,
2025     _removedConnection: false,
2027     _removedContLen: false,
2028     _removedTE: false,
2029     _contentLength: null,
2031     _hasBody: true,
2032     _trailer: '',
2034     finished: false,
2035     _headerSent: false,
2036     socket:
2038      Socket {
2039        connecting: false,
2041        _hadError: false,
2042        _handle: [TCP],
2044        _parent: null,
2045        _host: null,
2046        _readableState: [ReadableState],
2048        readable: true,
2049        _events: [Object],
2051        _eventsCount: 8,
2052        _maxListeners: undefined,
2053        _writableState: [WritableState],
2055        writable: true,
2056        allowHalfOpen: true,
2058        _sockname: null,
2059        _pendingData: null,
2061        _pendingEncoding: '',
2062        server: [Server],
2064        _server: [Server],
2065        timeout: 120000,
2066        parser: [HTTPParser],
2068        on: [Function: socketOnWrap],
2069        _paused: false,
2071        _httpMessage: [Circular],
2072        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 178,
2074        [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
2075        [Symbol(timeout)]:
2076         Timeout {
2078           _called: false,
2079           _idleTimeout: 120000,
2080           _idlePrev: [TimersList],
2083           _idleNext: [TimersList],
2084           _idleStart: 1148319,
2086           _onTimeout: [Function: bound ],
2087           _timerArgs: undefined,
2089           _repeat: null,
2090           _destroyed: false,
2091           [Symbol(unrefed)]: true,
2093           [Symbol(asyncId)]: 179,
2094           [Symbol(triggerId)]: 178 },
2095        [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
2097        [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0 },
2098     connection:
2100      Socket {
2101        connecting: false,
2103        _hadError: false,
2104        _handle: [TCP],
2105        _parent: null,
2107        _host: null,
2108        _readableState: [ReadableState],
2109        readable: true,
2111        _events: [Object],
2112        _eventsCount: 8,
2114        _maxListeners: undefined,
2115        _writableState: [WritableState],
2116        writable: true,
2118        allowHalfOpen: true,
2119        _sockname: null,
2121        _pendingData: null,
2122        _pendingEncoding: '',
2123        server: [Server],
2125        _server: [Server],
2126        timeout: 120000,
2128        parser: [HTTPParser],
2129        on: [Function: socketOnWrap],
2131        _paused: false,
2132        _httpMessage: [Circular],
2133        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 178,
2135        [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
2136        [Symbol(timeout)]:
2138         Timeout {
2139           _called: false,
2140           _idleTimeout: 120000,
2142           _idlePrev: [TimersList],
2143           _idleNext: [TimersList],
2145           _idleStart: 1148319,
2146           _onTimeout: [Function: bound ],
2148           _timerArgs: undefined,
2149           _repeat: null,
2151           _destroyed: false,
2152           [Symbol(unrefed)]: true,
2153           [Symbol(asyncId)]: 179,
2155           [Symbol(triggerId)]: 178 },
2156        [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
2158        [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0 },
2160     _header: null,
2161     _onPendingData: [Function: bound updateOutgoingData],
2163     _sent100: false,
2164     _expect_continue: false,
2166     req: [Circular],
2167     locals: [Object: null prototype] {},
2169     [Symbol(isCorked)]: false,
2171     [Symbol(outHeadersKey)]: [Object: null prototype] { 'x-powered-by': [Array] } },
2172  route:
2174   Route {
2175     path: '/create',
2176     stack: [ [Layer], [Layer] ],
2178     methods: { post: true } },
2179  body: {} }
```

According to all the documentation, examples, and tutorials I have looked at I am supposed to get the trigger_id from the body of the request, and I think I am supposed to be able to get data from the response params. However, the params, query, and body from the request are all empty.

Example: https://github.com/slackapi/template-slash-command-and-dialogs

Tutorial: https://scotch.io/tutorials/create-a-custom-slack-slash-command-with-nodejs-and-express#toc-building-a-url-shortener-slash-command

As a side note: I was not explicitly following the tutorial or using the example; I was referencing what they did to try and figure out what I did wrong.

```
1995  params: {},
1996  query: {}
```

and

```
2179  body: {}
```

So is there supposed to be data in body, query, or params? I believe so from what I have seen online, but this is my first attempt at a slack bot and at least from what I've seen Slack does not have the best documentation, so it is very plausible that I am calling it wrong somehow??

Update, this is the route I call on my server:

```
app.post('/create', jsonParser, function(req, res) {
  console.log(req);
  var {
    text, trigger_id
  } = req.body;
  // if (reqBody.token != botToken) {
  //   res.status(403).end("Access forbidden")
  // } else {
  res.status(200).end() // best practice to respond with empty 200 status code
  //Sample Dialog response from the GitHub example, to test if route is working
  const dialog = {
    token: botToken,
    trigger_id: trigger_id,
    dialog: JSON.stringify({
      title: 'Submit a helpdesk ticket',
      callback_id: 'submit-ticket',
      submit_label: 'Submit',
      elements: [{
        label: 'Title',
        type: 'text',
        name: 'title',
        value: text,
        hint: '30 second summary of the problem',
      }, {
        label: 'Description',
        type: 'textarea',
        name: 'description',
        optional: true,
      }, {
        label: 'Urgency',
        type: 'select',
        name: 'urgency',
        options: [{
          label: 'Low',
          value: 'Low'
        }, {
          label: 'Medium',
          value: 'Medium'
        }, {
          label: 'High',
          value: 'High'
        }, ],
      }, ],
    }),
  };
  // open the dialog by calling dialogs.open method and sending the payload
  bot.dialog.open({
      dialog
    }).then(console.log)
});
```

Comment: Hi. Most likely there is a bug in your code. please to post the actual code you are using (the relevant part for receiving the request from Slack).

Comment: @ErikKalkoken, I really don't have any code to post, all I am doing is typing my Slash command in the slack channel which makes a `POST` request to the slack server, and this is the response I receive from this request. I'll update the question to put the route I'm calling, but it's just a log essentially because variables are undefined.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. how do you expect your slash command to work if you have no code running?

Comment: @ErikKalkoken I just updated the question with the code you requested. I am trying to figure out how to receive data related to the Slash command from Slack, which is not being sent.

Comment: ok. thanks for posting the code.

Comment: Would suggest testing your endpoint by simulating a Slack request, e.g. with [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/). You can see [here](https://api.slack.com/slash-commands#app_command_handling) how they look.

Comment: What is the purpose of having `jsonParser` in your route? Slash commands are not in JSON.

Comment: My guess is that is where you problem is. also, if you look at the template the route for the slash command is defined without a json parser: `app.post('/command', (req, res) => {`

Comment: @Erikkalkoken I did what you suggested and removed the `jsonParser`, but now `req.body` is `undefined`

Comment: @ErikKalkoken, I got it!!!! Thanks to your link to the slash command documentation I realized that the data being sent is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and not `JSON` so I added `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));` and recived the data I should. Is there any way I can gift points to you for your help? If not you can answer the question and I'll mark it as correct so you get points. Thanks alot!

Comment: Glad you found the bug! Its not possible to gift "points", but I am to post the solution as answer and would appreciate if you upvote it and mark it as solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason your body is empty is that your current code assumes the request from Slack is sent as encoded in JSON. Instead it is encoded as standard POST request (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`).

Replacing

`app.post('/create', jsonParser, function(req, res) {`

with

`app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))`

Will do the trick.